# How to Get Rid of Windows XP Mode When Running Oracle Forms and Reports Builder?

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, oracleforms, oraclereports

In our office, we use Windows XP Mode virtual pc to be able to run Oracle Forms and Reports builder. If we try to open .fmb and .rdf files outside the virtual machine (Windows 7) the .fmb and .fmx cannot be opened properly and also we were not able to compile the files. I do not know the reason behind it. I want to get rid of this Windows XP Mode virtual pc already.

Comment: Can you please state your question more specifically?

Comment: _What is the actual error message?_. "cannot be opened properly" is a completely useless description. I guess there is some kind of development environment you need to install.

Comment: Oracle Forms Designer has stopped working.

Comment: But in XP Mode, it just works without crashing.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which Developer Suite version you use, but I presume that it is one that isn't certified nor supported on MS Windows 7. Check the certification matrices on My Oracle Support.

Reading forum discussions, I've seen that people *managed* to install & use Forms (being that 6i, 9i, 10gR1) on Windows 7 although, as I've said, it isn't supported. Try to Google for it - you'll probably get many questions and few answers, but - be patient. I, unfortunately, don't have a link to a working solution. How come? I don't need it.

Here's why: I don't use Windows XP Mode, but I installed Oracle VirtualBox and created a virtual machine which runs under MS Windows XP. Onto it, I installed the "old" Forms & Reports which is (was) - actually - certified & supported on that operating system version. Everything works just fine.

What is the advantage of such an approach? Periodically I get a new computer. Instead of going through a *painful* installation every now and then, I just copy the virtual machine onto a new computer and have everything up & running in a matter of *minutes*. I suggest you do the same.

Alternatively, upgrade your application (which means developer tools as well) to a higher, supported version on the operating system you use.

Comment: We use Oracle Developer Suite 10g

Comment: Me too; as I've said, on a VirtualBox under XP.